# Terraform AWS not accessing localstack

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, localstack

I'm having trouble getting a terraform AWS provider to talk to [localstack](https://github.com/localstack/localstack).  Whatever I try I just get the same error:

```
Error: error configuring Terraform AWS Provider: error validating provider credentials: error calling sts:GetCallerIdentity: InvalidClientTokenId: The security token included in the request is invalid.
    status code: 403, request id: dc96c65d-84a7-4e64-947d-833195464538
```

This error suggest that the provider is making contact with a HTTP server but the credentials are being rejected (as per any [403](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403)).  You might imagine the problem is that I'm feeding in the wrong credentials (through environment variables).

However the hostname `local-aws` exists in my `/etc/hosts` file, but `blahblahblah` does not.  If I swap the endpoint to point to `http://blahblahblah:4566` I still get the same 403.  So I think the problem is that the provider isn't using my local endpoint.  I can't work out why.

```
resource "aws_secretsmanager_secret_version" "foo" {
  secret_id = aws_secretsmanager_secret.foo.id
  secret_string = "bar"
}

resource "aws_secretsmanager_secret" "foo" {
    name = "rabbitmq_battery_emulator"
}

provider "aws" {
  region = "eu-west-2"
  endpoints {
    secretsmanager = "http://local-aws:4566"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Firstly check that localstack is configured to run `sts`.  In docker-compose this was just the SERVICES environment variable:

```yaml
services:
  local-aws:
    image: localstack/localstack
    environment:
      EDGE_PORT: 4566
      SERVICES: secretsmanager, sts
```

Then make sure that you set the `sts` endpoint as well as the service you require:

```
provider "aws" {
  region = "eu-west-2"
  endpoints {
    sts = "http://local-aws:4566"
    secretsmanager = "http://local-aws:4566"
  }
}
```

Comment: Coupling, sorry I'm late to the party. I had sts and secretsmanager configured as you mentioned above yet still got the same error message.

Comment: to let know other people, if you use in terraform this datasource:
`data "aws_caller_identity" "current" {}`
you will probably have the same problem - is also uses sts thingy. So this solution here is your solution.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the SERVICES and sts endpoint config mentioned by @philip-couling, I also had to remove a `terraform` block from my main.tf:

```
#terraform {
#  backend "s3" {
#    bucket = "valid-bucket"
#    key    = "terraform/state/account/terraform.tfstate"
#    region = "eu-west-1"
#  }
#  required_providers {
#    local = {
#      version = "~> 2.1"
#    }
#  }
#}
```